# How to stop Maven upgrading to latest Google Cloud SDK

Tags: maven, google-app-engine

I have just deployed my latest code to GCP. I use maven and recently migrated from com.google.appengine 1.9.58 to the latest com.google.cloud.tools using appengine-maven-plugin.

The version I deployed last month was the Cloud SDK version 265.0.0. When I deployed my new code today it upgraded me to 267.0.0. How do I prevent this from happening and control which SDK version I'm on.

I tried adding a dependancy to my POM:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
  <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>265.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But this failed.
As per my comment, the Cloud SDK upgrades to the latest when I run mvn appengine:deploy or mvn appengine:run

Thanks
TimN

POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <groupId>com.company.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxxyyydb</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <appengine.app.version>1</appengine.app.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.6.1</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-gcs-client</artifactId>
            <version>0.6</version>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.58</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.objectify</groupId>
            <artifactId>objectify</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdo-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.mpkorstanje</groupId>
            <artifactId>simmetrics-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>display-dependency-updates</goal>
                            <goal>display-plugin-updates</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <projectId>xxxyyydb</projectId>
                    <version>1</version>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Maven does not automatically update dependencies. You are probably looking at the wrong place.

Comment: It happened when I did an mvn package followed by an mvn appengine:run, so something in maven caused a re-download of the new Cloud SDK. Ideas?

Comment: Then please add your POM to the question. If you inherit the configuration of the appengine plugin, please add that as well.

Comment: POM file added to original post. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I wasn't able to find anything that could cause this automatic update in your pom.xml file. Could you tell me if you use a start-up script?

Comment: It happens when I run the command mvn appengine:run or appengine:deploy. So now I force to use Could SDK 269, whereas I was previously using 267.

Answer (score 1):

I found (and read!) the User Guide to the appengine-maven-plugin:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-maven-plugin/blob/master/USER_GUIDE.md

Setting the cloudSdkVersion in the configuration section of the plugin in my pom.xml allowed me to force the SDK version. Without it, the plugin always downloads the latest Cloud SDK.

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
           <projectId>xxxyyyProjectID</projectId>
           <version>1</version>
           <cloudSdkVersion>267.0.0</cloudSdkVersion>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: This worked for me, but appengine:run insisted on replacing current version: 347 with a differently named xxxbundled-python.zip which is also 347.

Comment: Then there is the Cloud SDK that has to be installed (with a windows installer in my case), because it turns out the maven sdk doesn't do gcloud beta auth application-default login  without which the devserver can't use datastore.  Wondering why that's in beta if its essential.